# IE JavaScript error : document.evaluate illegal # character

Tags: javascript, xpath, bookmarklet, document.evaluate

this script is developed to support only IE

I have this:

```
var result = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
```

with a known xpath;

the xpath is:

```
id("productTitle")
```

why do i get this error message:

```
Error ! This name may not contain the '#' character:

-->#<--comment
```

a working example, simple one : http://jsfiddle.net/gWpcU/6/

the example that crashes : http://jsfiddle.net/YkwTM/

Comment: Can you post the XPath expression that causes the error? It would help a lot.

Comment: Is this in IE, or all browsers?

Comment: This is the only similar reference I could find... http://sourceforge.net/projects/html-xpath/forums/forum/380919/topic/1337251 Is that any help?

Comment: it is, just got a point from where to start the reseacrh, i will post the result after i get it

Comment: The reason I ask about IE is because I remember getting that error a long time ago, and it was something to do with array keys. IIRC they cannot start with certain characters... maybe # is one of them? But then there doesn't seem to be any kind of key reference going on in your code, so... probably not :-/

Comment: my app is a bookmarklet, and i must develop the ie support as a module, and for the other browsers as another module

Comment: lol, thats the code i used :))

Comment: I once had this too and I am not that sure right now, but it happened if the context node is the document, try to use document.documentElement, if I remember right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get the error message in the example document is because xPath is trying to reread the document to do its own thing on it, and whenever it sees a `"<!"`, the script parser gives an error.  Going through and removing all cases of `"<!"` (namely, the `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and all the `<!--` comments), makes the page work without errors.  I would paste it here, but the answer becomes too long: so you can do that yourself.

Conversely, pasting the `<!DOCTYPE html>` into your working example also makes it get that error.